# Checking the inequality of several variables in python without knowing their value

Tags: python, string, equality, inequality

I have four string variables: `a,b,c,d`. I can't know their values (they are assigned randomly), and I don't care. I only need to make sure that every single on of them is different from others and there are not two variables with the same value. I tried

```
if a != b != c != d:
    return true
```

but it doesn't work. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this?

```
assert len({a, b, c, d}) == 4 # set of 4 distinct elements should be 4

if len({a, b, c, d}) == 4:
    return True
```

The reason your conditions don’t work

```
>>> 1 != 2 != 1
True
```

From the above example, `1 != 2` and `2 != 1`, hence passing the condition. It doesn’t check your first and third variable's equality.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the naive approach:

```
if a != b and a != c and a != d and b != c and b != d and c != d:
    # do something
```

Or you can make use of the fact that a set cannot hold the same hashable value twice:

```
if len(set([a, b, c, d])) == 4:
    # do something
```

Or, a shorter way of writing the same:

```
if len({a, b, c, d}) == 4:
    # do something
```

The reason your code doesn't work is because you're really doing this:

```
if a != b and b != c and c != d:
    return true
```

So, it only checks part of what you need to check, it checks if all of the values directly following each other are equal, but not whether values more than one position apart are equal.

Comment: Your last statement is wrong. `((2 != 2) != True) != False` gives `True` whereas `2 != 2 != True != False` gives `False`, they are not equivalent. Chained operations are evaluated with logical and.

Comment: @Jarvis, you're right - will update

Answer (score 1):

You cannot cannot chain comparisons like this. Below is one way to do it using if statements, although it is messy.

```py
if (a != b and a != c and a != d
        and b != c and b != d and c !=d):
        return True
```

A nifty approach (albeit with some minor speed and space costs) is the following:

```py
things_to_see_if_unique = [a, b, c, d]
if len(things_to_see_if_unique) == len(set(things_to_see_if_unique)):
    return True
```